# My Macbook doesn't import or copy photos from Galaxy S3

Tags: file-transfer

There are 663 photos in my camera. I want to share some of them them via computer with my mother who does not have a smartphone.

- My phone and computer are connected via USB cable.
- The [Android File Transfer](https://www.android.com/intl/en_in/filetransfer/) app is installed and working up to the point of showing me a window on my computer with choices of files to transfer.

However, when I click on **DCIM** or **Pictures** nothing comes up. Similarly, nothing happens when I click on **Camera**.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I get those photos from my phone to show up in my computer? And will they be in both places?  I'd like to keep them in my phone also.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the mobile in Mass Storage (MSC) mode instead of MTP mode. You'll find this setting in Connectivity section. MSC mode will mount the memory card to the PC just like USB storage. You can now copy contents more easily (or)
Use the Samsung's KIES software for handling all the media.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone and computer are on the same network there is no need of USB cable. Just install [WeLine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cc.weline&hl=en)(or airdroid) and transfer files between your phone and computer as it is supported on PC and MAC. If you are not on the same network follow the steps below,

1. First of all, if you are Windows user you should download the [USB driver for the Galaxy SIII](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I535MBBVZW) and install it to your computer. While if you are a Mac user you do not need to install any drivers or software.
2. Connect these two devices using a micro USB cable.
   On your phone's screen the prompt will appear informing you that you have connected to the computer.
3. Drag down the notification area and select the option you want to use for your device. The options include:

   - Connected as a media device -> Media device (MTP) -> Use this option if you want Windows Explorer or Mac Finder manually transfer files between PC and your phone or if you want to utilize Windows Media Player.
   - Connected as a media device -> Camera (PTP) -> Use this option if you want to use your phone as a camera.
4. Once selected the option as MTP or PTP you can use your device as either MTP media device(file transfer) or PTP media device(camera)

[Reference](http://inside-galaxy.blogspot.co.il/2013/04/samsung-galaxy-s3-how-to-connect-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Does you Macbook supports wifi?**

- If yes then see this [guide](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2812516?hl=en) by Google to know how to enable Wi-Fi hotspot in your Android device.
- If not then no issues. We can use USB tethering here to get the job done. See this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32152/how-to-enable-usb-tethering-on-your-android-phone-to-mac-os-x-lion) to know how to setup USB tethering between a Mac and an Android phone.

We're going to use [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) to stream the images from Android to Mac for viewing, or optionally choosing to download them into computer for any later use.

#### Instructions:

1. Install [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) from Play Store.
2. Enable USB tethering or Wi-Fi hotspot in your phone (connect Mac to this hotspot as well).
3. Launch [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid), go to **Tools → Tethering (Others)** and you'll be shown a URL which would be:

   - For USB tethering -- `http://192.168.42.129:8888`
   - For Wi-Fi hotspot -- `http://192.168.43.1:8888`

   <sub>(The URL might vary depending upon how your device's OEM changed Android's code (details irrelevant here).)</sub>
4. Enter the URL in a browser of your Macbook ([AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) supports [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html#) more) and choose **Accept** on the Android screen.
5. The default screen would look like:

   [image: Default screen]
6. Using this app now is trivial since options are easy to understand and use.

   - Anyhow, open **Photos** icon to see images inside your Android device. You can double-click any image to see in full-screen and use direction keys of keyboard to browse them full-screen.
   - You can choose to download individual or multiple images by clicking the checkbox on desired images(s) and choosing **Download** option.

#### Objectives achieved:

- Photos can exists on both sides.
- Photos can be viewed without transferring them in computer.
- No internet connection is needed to view/transfer images.