# How to upgrade my Android from Linux?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, updates, linux, ota-update, asus-zenfone-5

Using Asus Zenfone 5, which I want to upgrade to Android Lollipop.

The instructions say that I have to copy the OTA files to my SD card from my PC, but unfortunately I use Linux (ubuntu and mint). I cannot connect to my sd card via the usb cable. Is there any way to copy the files to the SD card from my Linux platform? Otherwise, can I use dropbox to get the file to the SD card somehow?

Comment: Have you tried using adb to transfer the files to the phone

Comment: Why cant you mount the device in Ubuntu/Mint? I do it all the time. And most of the time it auto mounts it like a flash drive. Are you getting errors while it's trying to connect? But yes, you can use a 3rd party storage to download it to the SD card, such as Dropbox, Google Drive and etc.

Answer (score 1):

The answers given were great but I felt something needed to be added: If you boot into Android, you should be able to download the OTA file directly from your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Download adb by typing in terminal:
`sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb`
**Setup adb**: You'll find plenty of tutorials on internet to setup adb.

Now type this in the terminal:

`adb push /path/to/file /path/to/paste`

Replace the paths with your corresponding ones

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to copy the files from PC into your SD card. Simplest is the Android's native MTP mode, which you might be having trouble with detecting the device in Ubuntu/Mint.

#### Method 1

You can use ADB as mentioned [here by Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/91901/96277). Setup ADB and detect device on your PC (see [Is there a minimal installation of ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42474/is-there-a-minimal-installation-of-adb)), open terminal and enter:

```
adb push <SOURCE> <DESTINATION>
```

where `<SOURCE>` would be the file location in your PC like `~/Downloads/OTA.zip` and `DESTINATION` would be file location in your Android device like `/sdcard/`.

E.g.:

```
adb push ~/Downloads/OTA_Lollipop.zip /sdcard/
```

#### Method 2

Some users report problems while setting up ADB in their PC. In that case, see this [method by ykasidit](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/95514/96277).

You would need to install an Android app named [MTP-Alternative USB drive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clearevo.mtp_alternative). (See **Method 4** for its detailed usage.)

#### Method 3

Use [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) which I covered [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/110152/96277).

#### Method 4

If all the above method fails to work somehow, then try my guide [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/106323/96277). See **Method #1** there for **MTP-Alternative's** usage, or try my **Method #3** there.

---

**Note** that all the aforesaid methods would work with Wi-Fi hotspot and USB-tethering.

Comment: You can also use a Micro SD card reader if the SD card is detachable.