# How to transfer (and then watch) video files from PC to my Android phone (mi4)?

Tags: video

I have an Android Xiaomi mi4 and I'd like to know if I can copy video files to it from my PC. Is there any straightforward way to do so ?

Comment: Which OS are you using on PC? If its Windows 7 or above then MTP mode in Android would work straight out of the box. If you're using Linux then it depends upon what does straightforward means to you, but the default is to use MTP. You can  take a look [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/91900/96277) or [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=install+mtp+). // There are also options like using [Airdroid](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/110152/96277) which would work on any desktop OS.

Comment: Do you want to copy the files manually each time – or would you like your "video storage" to be synced between your PC and your Android device? Or would you like to hear about both options?

Comment: Using a USB cable is a straightforward way to do the file transfer. But if you want to do it wirelessly there are lots of app in play store which does this but your phone and PC have to be connected to the same network or you could use your phone's hotspot feature but that requires a computer a wifi-receiver to receive file via hotspot or simply a laptop will do. I personally use Xender for file transfers as I'm mostly connected with the same network. Incase I'm not I use my mobile hotspot feature to transfer file from and to my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it quite easily if you have installed the correct drivers on your computer. If you want to do it wireless, AirDroid (http://web.airdroid.com/) can be a solution.

Comment: And what is the need of the drivers? I've three different phones running different Android versions, and I never explicitly installed drivers for any of them for the purpose of transferring files.

Comment: Indeed I now it works out of the box in many cases, but few phones are less easy to deal with regarding usb drivers. Can you try installing the correct driver from this website ? http://androidxda.com/download-xiaomi-usb-drivers

Comment: @victorleduc since when does AIRdroid need a cable? Sure, it *can* be used via USB. But as the name AIR(droid) suggests, it was built to work wirelessly over WiFi. Last time I've used that app (a few years ago) it worked that way – and I very much doubt the dev removed that feature. Au contraire, it now even works over the internet if you want that (which was when I stopped using it).

Comment: You are right. That is why I said "If you want to do it wireless"

Answer (score 0):

The *official* Xiaomi Mi PC Suite should solve your issue. The Global (English) version can be found [here](http://pcsuite.mi.com/).

In case it doesn't, you may try to download USB driver for your device manually on MIUI forum through this [link](http://androidxda.com/download-xiaomi-usb-drivers). However, do take note that these drivers are *not officially* endorsed by Xiaomi.

Comment: I own a Mi4W myself and it really doesn't connect to PC out of the box.

Comment: Note that the link to the official Xiaomi Mi PC Suite is already dead. You might still be able to find alternative sources for the download, but be careful of suspicious sites. Also, the particular link to Android XDA (not the XDA Devs) is also dead.